# Laravel 8: old() helper is not functioning correctly for <select>

Tags: php, laravel

I followed this [guide](https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/simplify-laravel-crud-controllers) of simplifying the controller. Sharing one form between `create` and `edit`

The `old()` helper is not working as expected with the `<select>`. 
Every time I submit the form when something is missing, the old selected option is there, but when I resubmit the form, it shows an error that the `<select>` field is required...

[image: Before Edit]

[image: After edit]

The string inputs is as follows:

```
<input type="text class="form-control @error('claimedBy') is-invalid @enderror" name="claimedBy" value="{{ old('claimedBy', $lostFound->claimedBy) }}">
```

But the select is like this:

```
<select class="form-select select-basic-single @error('handover') is-invalid @enderror" name="handover">
  <option value="{{ old('handover', $lostFound->handover ?? 'null') }}" selected disabled>{{ old('handover', $lostFound->handover ?? 'Handed to') }}</option>
  <option value="police"> Police </option>
  <option value="owner"> Owner </option>
  <option value="warehouse"> In Warehouse </option>
</select>
```

Make the option value `null` and the text `Handed to` if no value is selected.

Comment: You will have to add the selected attribute on each option that was selected, like ```{{ old('handover') == 'owner' ? 'selected' : '' }}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `disabled` from the option. A disabled option will not be submitted.

There is a missing comma in your input field by `type="text"`

old

```
type="text class="form-control @error('claimedBy') is-invalid @enderror"
```

new

```
type="text" class="form-control @error('claimedBy') is-invalid @enderror"
```

Comment: I changed disabled with readonly and it worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ (old('handover') ? old('handover') : $lostFound->handover ?? '') == $lostFound->handover ? 'selected' : '' }}
```

What is doing here is:
if (if old(handover) true old(handover) else $lostFound->handover default '') equals $id true selected false ''

also remove disabled,  and it is important that u set '' for value of the input so that u can check for it and return proper error if needed. What i like to do is prepend option with '' value with text like "Please select one" and then u can always check for it if it wasn't selected. Then u could use disabled approach, but with setting old value as selected and disabled it won't post value.